# Вывод php или html-разметки на странице

Tags: html, php

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите, как сделать отображение php- и html-тегов между [code] [/code]...
`<code>` и `<pre>` не помогают...

Пробовал с помощью highlight_string(), но она как-то неадекватно работает

```
preg_replace("#\[code\](.*)\[/code\]#isUu", highlight_string("\\1", true), $text);
```

через раз работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может htmlspecialchars?

Comment: Пробовал, тоже не катит

Comment: <?php   
$a="<h1>Hello</h1>";  
$a=htmlspecialchars($a);  
echo "$a"; //выведет <h1>Hello</h1>   
?>  
Разве это не то, что надо?

Comment: @mazanax: что значит "не катит"? Что вы делаете, и что получается на выходе (HTML)?

Comment: Не катит - значит, что выводится форматированный текст...

$text = preg_replace("#\[code\](.*)\[/code\]#isUu", htmlspecialchars("\\1"), $text); \\ при [code]<b>blah-blah</b>[/code] 

выводит жирный blah-blah

$text = preg_replace("#\[code\](.*)\[/code\]#isUu", highlight_string("\\1", true), $text); \\ при [code]<b>blah-blah</b>[/code] 

аналогично

Answer (score 0):

А может лучше: [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter)

Comment: Использую, но текст надо еще и на сервере обрабатывать

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$code = '<?php 
 $a="<h1>Hello</h1>";
 $a=htmlspecialchars($a);
 echo "$a"; //выведет <h1>Hello</h1> 
?>';

echo '<pre>', htmlspecialchars($code), '</pre>';

?>
```